# keep response key nodejs sequelize on null with vue2

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, sequelize.js

my response json

if null

```
dm_personal: null
```

if not null
if null

```
dm_personal: { id: 1 }
```

how to keep the key of response on null ?

or how to implement on vue2 if i fetch / load single data that set data() { return {} }

when its null it shown cannot read on null

here is my input

```
  <vue-autosuggest
   id="vi-dm_personal-penanggung_jawab"
   v-model="form.transportir.dm_personal.full_name" // here is problem null
   :suggestions=" [{ data: form.transportir.dm_personal.dm_personals }]" // here is problem null
...
```

in method or other we can use elvis operator like **data?.data** but in html element for v-model or any properties ( like :suggestions ) , how to best practice to clear the problem ???

Answer (score 0):

Vue will only create the property if the parent object already exists but it will not create if the parent property value is `null`.

```
form: {
  transportir: {
    dm_personal: {}
  }
}
```

So what you can do it convert the `null` into an object `literal`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    form: {
        transportir: {
        dm_personal: null
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    if (!this.form.transportir.dm_personal) {
        this.form.transportir.dm_personal = {}
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="form.transportir.dm_personal.full_name"/>
</div>
```